# indent before theorem/assumption

Tags: environments, indentation

Please see below my try to add an indent before Assumption line.      Please see the packages in the preamble which I used in my actual document. I read that ragged2e kills indentation. 
Eventhough I changed `\usepackage{tabularx,ragged2e,booktabs,caption}` to `\usepackage{tabularx}`, there is no indent added before Assumption.

```
\documentclass[letterpaper, 12 pt, conference,onecolumn,draftcls]{ieeeconf}  %%
\IEEEoverridecommandlockouts                              % This command is only
                                                          % needed if you want to
                                                          % use the \thanks command
\overrideIEEEmargins
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage[dvips]{graphicx}
%\usepackage{psfig,subfigure}
\usepackage{epsfig}
\usepackage{graphicx}
%comment below if any problem
%\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{here}
\usepackage{mathptmx} % assumes new font selection scheme installed
\usepackage{times} % assumes new font selection scheme installed
%\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{bm}
%\usepackage{sansmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
%\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{float}
%\usepackage{textcomp}
%\usepackage{txfonts}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{tabularx,ragged2e,booktabs,caption}
\usepackage[mathscr]{euscript}
\DeclareMathOperator*{\argmax}{arg\,max}
\usepackage{ntheorem}\theoremseparator{.}
\newtheorem{mydef}{Definition}\theoremseparator{.}
\newtheorem{myalgo}{Algorithm}\theoremseparator{.}
\newtheorem{myassum}{Assumption}\theoremseparator{.}
\newtheorem{myprop}{Proposition}\theoremseparator{.}
\newtheorem{mytheo}{Theorem}\theoremseparator{.}
\newtheorem{myproof}{Proof}\theoremseparator{.}
\DeclareMathOperator*{\argmin}{arg\,min}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\Centering}m{#1}}
\renewcommand\tabularxcolumn[1]{C{#1}}
\begin{document}

\indent\begin{myassum}\label{asum_contro} \rm{The value of $(A,B)$
are known.}
\end{myassum}

\par\begin{myassum}\label{asum_contro} \rm{The value of $(A,B)$ are
known.}
\end{myassum}

\parindent30pt\begin{myassum}\label{asum_contro} \rm{The value of
$(A,B)$ are known.}
\end{myassum}

Please help me add an indent just before Assumption 1. I mean the
assumptions should start as a paragraph.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: `\rm` is outdated and furthermore does not have an argument. Also, 90% of your loaded packages are irrelevant for your issue.

Comment: Quite a few of the packages you load are obsolete, and some (e.g., `subfigure`) are actively deprecated, i.e., they shouldn't be loaded at all. I suspect that many packages aren't even needed for your documents.

Comment: I use Ctex..an oldversion...I kept those packages in my question as I have no idea whether any one of them is related to the issue. In the orignal doc which has lots f theorems and Tables I use those packages as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `ntheorem` package provides `\theoremindent`,which has to be used before `\ntheorem` with `\theoremindent\parindent, i.e. without`{}` pair.

Using theorem styles would be even better.

```
\documentclass[letterpaper, 12 pt, conference,onecolumn,draftcls]{IEEEconf}  %%
%\IEEEoverridecommandlockouts                              % This command is only
                                                          % needed if you want to
                                                          % use the \thanks command
%\overrideIEEEmargins
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{graphicx}
%comment below if any problem
%\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
\usepackage{here}
\usepackage{mathptmx} % assumes new font selection scheme installed
\usepackage{times} % assumes new font selection scheme installed
%\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{bm}
%\usepackage{sansmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
%\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{float}
%\usepackage{textcomp}
%\usepackage{txfonts}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{tabularx,ragged2e,booktabs,caption}
\usepackage[mathscr]{euscript}
\DeclareMathOperator*{\argmax}{arg\,max}
\usepackage{ntheorem}\theoremseparator{.}
\newtheorem{mydef}{Definition}\theoremseparator{.}
\newtheorem{myalgo}{Algorithm}\theoremseparator{.}
\theoremindent\parindent
\newtheorem{myassum}{Assumption}\theoremseparator{.}
\newtheorem{myprop}{Proposition}\theoremseparator{.}
\newtheorem{mytheo}{Theorem}\theoremseparator{.}
\newtheorem{myproof}{Proof}\theoremseparator{.}
\DeclareMathOperator*{\argmin}{arg\,min}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\Centering}m{#1}}
\renewcommand\tabularxcolumn[1]{C{#1}}
\begin{document}

\begin{myassum}\label{asum_contro} \textnormal{The value of $(A,B)$
are known.}
\end{myassum}

\begin{myassum}\label{asum_contro} \textnormal{The value of $(A,B)$ are
known.}
\end{myassum}

\begin{myassum}\label{asum_contro} \textnormal{The value of
$(A,B)$ are known.}
\end{myassum}

Please help me add an indent just before Assumption 1. I mean the
assumptions should start as a paragraph.
\end{document}
```